# Ads API: Implementing Partner Categories asks for account to be white listed. How to get white listed?

Tags: facebook, pmd, facebook-ads-api

It seems that an account needs to be white listed somewhere to be able to use the new Partner Category feature. Anybody familiar with this? We tested with the account that is white listed for API access and get error back from Facebook with the message that the account is not white listed. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to be whitelisted to use Partner Categories, you have asked this question some time ago but if you are still having the same issue please file a bug through http://developers.facebook.com/bugs and tag it as an ads-api issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Partner Categories feature is currently only available to advertisers in the US - see https://www.facebook.com/help/353223368111533 for more information - this applies to the API also